# Unable to Boot Simulator - Xcode 14.0.1

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I am running XCode 14.0.1 on mac ios 12.6. When I try to run any app in any simulator I get and alert:
"Unable to boot the Simulator. Interrupted System Call."

I have followed steps described in other posts. I've gone to About this Mac > Storage > Manage > Developer and deleted XCode Cache. I've deleted and re-added simulators in XCode itself. I even re-installed XCode. Nothing works.

When I check the "Detail" button in my "Unable to Boot" alert, I also get this:

"Failed to start launchd_sim: could not bind to session, launchd_sim may have crashed or quit responding
Domain: com.apple.SimLaunchHostService.RequestError
Code: 4"
Does anyone have any clues as to what is happening?
Thanks

Comment: "I've deleted and re-added simulators in XCode itself" But did you try just deleting all the simulators directly in the Finder?

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your app first.

The other method is to clear the derived data for your project.

By going to Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Derived Data -> Select and delete the folder for your project.